# Ubercart show Prices without Tax For specific Role

Tags: 7, ubercart, users

I need to show prices without tax for specific user role. Other available roles should see prices with included tax.
How I can achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ubercart adds taxes in [hook_entity_view_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_view_alter/7)( uc_taxes_entity_view_alter)

So I implement hook_entity_view_alter in my module

```
function mymodule_entity_view_alter(&$build, $entity_type) {
  global $user;

  if($user && in_array(constant('SOME_USER_ROLE'), $user->roles)) {
    return;
  } 

  // ...
}
```

Also unimplement uc_taxes implemetation of hook_entity_view_alter using hook_module_implements_alter

```
function mymodule_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {
  if (in_array($hook, array( 'entity_view_alter'))) {
    unset($implementations['uc_taxes']);
  }
}
```